# Global style not working - vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, global

It's my understanding that all non-scoped styles defined in the main vue file are supposed to be global. So, why is it that the following does not work? The import works globally but all components ignore the body style. I have to specify the font-family within each component for it to work. How do I set the font globally so that all components inherit the style?

```
<style>
@import '../node_modules/npm-font-open-sans/open-sans.css'
body, html {font-family: 'Open Sans'}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead I would suggest to override `$body-font-family` variable in the `main.styl` file with your own font it should work

Comment: I don't have a main.styl file.